# how to explode a string to use in a image tag

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-blade, laravel-8

i stored multiple images in database column in string format like
`"image1 image2 image3"` by using `implode(" ",$imagesArray)`
now i want to explode this string and want to use this in an image source name like i am trying below

```
@foreach (explode(" ",$images) as $item)
<img src="{{ asset('storage/images'.$item) }}">
@endforeach
```

its split it like

```
 0 => "[{"image":"image3.png"
  1 => "image3.png"
  2 => "image3.png"}]"
```

and i want it to split like

```
 0 => "image3.png"
  1 => "image3.png"
  2 => "image3.png"
```

yes images are stored locally in storage/images path,

and yes $Images contains

```
[{"image":"image1.png image2.png image3.png"}]
```

how can i use each image for image src please help me i am new in php and laravel, thanks in advance

Comment: What error you get when you try the @foreach loop

Comment: its's not split the string as i expected, it explode it like,  0 => "[{"image":"1606378172_444px-Apache_NetBeans_Logo.svg.png"
  1 => "1606378172_iconfinder_android_245977.png"
  2 => "1606378172_iconfinder_Edit-01_1976055.png"}]"

Comment: try `asset('storage/images/'.$item)` you are missing on `/`

Comment: What is the content of `$images` before the foreach loop?

Comment: [{"image":"image1.png image2.png image3.png"}]

Comment: I deployed your code here https://rextester.com/ORIWY75811

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you show us how you get the data from the DB, we can probably avoid the decoding to an array used below.

From what you show, it looks like you have a JSON string there. If so, you shouldnt explode it right away but first decode it and get the prop you want, then explode that:

```
@php
     $string = '[{"image":"image1.png image2.png image3.png"}]';
     $rows   = json_decode($string, true);
@endphp

@foreach ($rows as $row)

     @php
        $imageStr = $row['image'] ?? '';
        $images   = explode(" ", $imageStr);
     @endphp

     @foreach ($images as $image)
        <img src="{{ asset('storage/images'.$image) }}">
     @endforeach

@endforeach
```

##NOTE
If I were doing this, I'd probably move the logic to the controller, add each image path to an array, pass that array to the view, and then have the view simply loop over that array outputting each image tag. This way all the view doesn't get cluttered up with all the logic.

Comment: thank you very much sir, i didn't knew about json string learned new thing today, it works perfectly,

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment `$images` is a JSON string, so you need to decode it first:

```
@foreach (explode(' ', json_decode($images, true)[0]['image'] ?? '') as $image)
    <img src="{{ asset('storage/images/'.$image) }}">
@endforeach
```

Comment: Note, this assumes the array will only ever have one element in it. That might be acceptable, though its probably better to account for more than one given it is an array.

Comment: it also works perfect and short, thanks for your precious time sir

Comment: @WesleySmith good point. I agree with you as you said in your answer that there is probably a way to avoid doing the JSON juggling entirely

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that array can have more than one element as pointed out in @WeslySmith's comment

```php
//Say images has value like
$images = ['{"image":"image1.png image2.png image3.png"}','{"image":"image4.png image5.png image6.png"}'];

$pathString = collect($images)->map(function($image) {
    return json_decode($image)->image;
})
  ->values()
  ->reduce(function($carry, $item){
      return $carry .= $item;
  });
```

And then

```
@foreach (explode(' ', $pathString as $image)
    <img src="{{ asset('storage/images/'.$image) }}">
@endforeach
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems the whole array is a JSON string, rather than it being a PHP array _containing JSON strings_

Comment: That said, the OP is using Laravel and getting this data from the DB so we could likely get rid of all the JSON stuff and just loop over the collection of DB rows directly if we could see that code.